React Router and MSAL Redirect Issue: Endless Login Page Loop
I'm using React Router and MSAL for authentication with Azure AD in my React application. After successful login, the app redirects to http://localhost:5173/home, but then quickly goes back to the login page (/ route) in a loop.
AuthGuard Component:
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const AuthGuard = ({ element }) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, userRole } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to={`/${userRole}`} /> : element;
};

PrivateRoute Component:

import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ role, children }) => {
  const { userRole } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return userRole === role ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

Issue:
The app goes into a loop, redirecting from the home page (http://localhost:5173/home) back to the login page repeatedly.
The login status and user role seem to be set correctly after authentication.
What I've Tried:

Checked the Azure AD App Registration Redirect URI.
Verified routes and authentication logic in React Router.
Added logs and debugging, but can't pinpoint the issue.

Any suggestions on why the app keeps looping back to the login page after successful authentication?

The loop likely stems from a conflict between route guards and authentication state. Ensure the AuthGuard and PrivateRoute components accurately reflect the authentication status and user roles

OP, were you able to find a solution? I'm experiencing the same looping behavior. If yes, can you share your findings?
